# why does glColor3f cause memory leak

Tags: opengl, memory-leaks

I called the following function in a MEX file (matlab) in a loop. It causes memory leak in glColor3f. The memory continue to increase. Is there any idea to solve it?

```
static GLuint createDisplayListWithColor(double *fM, int fNum, double *vM, int vNum, GLfloat *ColorM, int colorNum)
{
    GLuint theShape;
    int i;
    double *fp;
    int vIndex, fNum2, vNum2;

    fNum2 = fNum * 2;
    vNum2 = vNum * 2;

    theShape = glGenLists (1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glNewList(theShape, GL_COMPILE);
    glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);


        for (i = 1; i <= fNum; i++) {
            fp = fM + i-1;
            vIndex = (int)fp[0] - 1;
            glColor3f(ColorM[vIndex], ColorM[vIndex + vNum], ColorM[vIndex + vNum2]);
            glVertex3d(vM[vIndex], vM[vIndex + vNum], vM[vIndex + vNum2] );

            vIndex = (int)fp[fNum] - 1;
            glColor3f(ColorM[vIndex], ColorM[vIndex + vNum], ColorM[vIndex + vNum2]);
            glVertex3d(vM[vIndex], vM[vIndex + vNum], vM[vIndex + vNum2] );

            vIndex = (int)fp[fNum2] - 1;
            glColor3f(ColorM[vIndex], ColorM[vIndex + vNum], ColorM[vIndex + vNum2]);
            glVertex3d(vM[vIndex], vM[vIndex + vNum], vM[vIndex + vNum2] );
               }

    glEnd ();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glEndList();
    return theShape;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, given the fact that each almost every OpenGL command it recorded in a Display List it's no surprise that a calling OpenGL commands in a loop within a Display List compilation will consume memory. Use `glDeleteLists` before program termination to delete all lists.

*But honestly*, why are you using Display Lists in the first place? Display Lists and Immediate Mode are deprecated. Even almost 10 years ago with the introduction of OpenGL-2 it was considered to remove them, and it was strongly recommended not to use them in new code.

Comment: @user2613981: BTW: the glutSwapBuffers makes no sense within a list compilation. SwapBuffers is not a OpenGL operation.